# Ident authentication fault for user

Tags: postgresql

I try to use PostgreSQL backup script [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Linux). I set the username at the config file and tried to run pg_backup.sh.

But I get "Ident authentication fault for user 'aquila'".(aquila is the username I am trying to connect with).

I created a .pgpass file at the home directory. The content of the file is like

```
*:*:*:aquila:<password> (I am sure password is correct).
```

I also tried to change pg_hba.conf file as;

```
local all all       md5
```

Also I tried

```
local all all       ident
```

Whatever I did, I couldn't achive to run this script because of this error.

How can I get rid of this error?

Thanks.

**pg_hba.conf**

```
#TYPE  DATABASE USER ADDRESS  METHOD

local  all      all           md5
host   all      all  0.0.0.0  md5 
host   all      all  ::1/128  ident
```

I did not share command-out parts of the file. This is the current pg_hba.conf file. But I also tried to add followings;

```
local  all      all                ident
local  all      all                trust
host   all      all 127.0.0.1/32   trust
```

Comment: try `local all all       trust` and restart Postgresql server

Comment: nope, still I get the same error :(

Comment: try `host all 127.0.0.1/32 trust`

Comment: I guess you mean "host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust". I tried but nothing changed.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to restart the server? Use `service postgresql restart` to restart the server. If it does not work, add to the question the entire content of your pg_hba.conf

Comment: I did restart the server. I will share pg_hba.conf.

Comment: Comment out the first line (the one with ident) The pg_hba.conf parser always uses the **first match**. (BTW Actual cause: possibly identd is not running on your server.)

Comment: @joop I guess, you mean "local  all      all                ident". I tried one of them at a time

Comment: For example; pg_dump --dbname=<dbname> --username=aquila --file=<file-name> --no-password. This runs witout any problem.

Comment: The 'ident' option is wrong (is not what you want). Use everywhere `md5`.

Comment: @TommasoDiBucchianico I tried to use md5 everywhere also. But still nothing changes.

Comment: mmmhhh, maybe are you editing the wrong pg_hba.conf? Do you have several server installed? What does the command `locate pg_hba.conf` say?

Comment: No, I have only one server. The output of the "locate pg_hba.conf" is;
"/usr/pgsql-9.3/share/pg_hba.conf.sample" and
"/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf"

I modify "/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I have changed

```
#TYPE  DATABASE USER ADDRESS  METHOD

local  all      all           md5
host   all      all  0.0.0.0  md5 
host   all      all  ::1/128  ident
```

to

```
#TYPE  DATABASE USER ADDRESS  METHOD

local  all      all           md5
host   all      all  0.0.0.0  md5 
host   all      all  ::1/128  md5
```

I really did't understand why this fixed the problem but it is fixed :)